# Timed Auto-Clear cells across multiple sheets in a Workbook

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkPXQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLXD.png)

The title pretty much says it all. In the workbook I created there are about 6 corresponding sheets. My goal is to have the information in those cells clear or reset to the blank workbook template that I created. I would like this to reset automatically every week. I sought help from other areas of the internet but I’m not sure I’m getting the help I need. I can provide a screenshot of my script but I need to know what I need to do to make this work or if I need to add or subtract code from my script. Or if this is even possible.  The images attached are of the script I am running which is not working. And of the template I created with the areas I’d like to have reset. So the image of the workbook should be what it looks like after it resets. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)